# The variational formulation of entropy

Tags: probability-theory, harmonic-analysis

For $f:\mathbb Z_2^n \to [0, \infty)$, the entropy of $f$ is defined as
$$
{\rm Ent}(f) = \mathbb E[f(X) \log f(X)] - \mathbb E f(X) \log(\mathbb E f(X)),
$$
where $X$ is a random element of $\mathbb Z_2^n$. The variational formulation of entropy claims that
$$
{\rm Ent}(f) = \sup\{\mathbb E[f(X) \times g(X)]~:~ \mathbb E e^{g(X)} \le 1, g:\mathbb Z_2^n \to \mathbb R \}.
$$
How can we prove it?

I know the hint is to define
$$
L(g, \lambda) = \mathbb E[f(X)g(X)] - \lambda (\mathbb E[g(X)] - 1).
$$
and then we just need to show that $\sup_g \inf_{\lambda \ge 0} L(g, \lambda) = {\rm Ent}(f)$. But I don't know what technique can be applied to find the extremal value of $L(g, \lambda)$.